# preg_replace replaces quotes with strange characters?

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, preg-replace

If I execute the following code:

```
$string =  'This is “Bob” Batman.';
echo $string . '<br>';
$string = preg_replace('/(["“”„]Bob["“„])/',  '-$1-', $string);
echo $string;
```

Then the outcome is

> This is “Bob” Batman.
>
> This is �-�Bob�-�� Batman.

Why is the last line not simply like this:

> This is -“Bob”- Batman.

Comment: The encoding is changing.

Comment: @Barman I did not find any encoding options for the preg_replace method. I guess there must be a way to use this function with special quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a formatting problem.

You can use the regex `u` flag to resolve your problem :

```
$string = preg_replace('/(["“”„]Bob["“”„])/u',  '-$1-', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with unicode mode:

```
echo preg_replace('/["“”„]Bob["“”„]/u',  '-$0-', $string);
//=> This is -“Bob”- Batman.
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cu4RL1/1)